# How to send multiform request having data and image using restkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

data { "firstName": "arun", "lastName": "kumar", "contactInfo" : { "email": "ak7896@gmail.com"},"password": "abcdefg"}

main (image to upload)

Above is my request structure for signup. How can i create a multiform request structure using restkit.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: my request mapping i am creating is like below:RKObjectMapping *signupRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [signupRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"data" :@{
                                                                       @"firstname":@"firstname", @"lastname":@"lastname", @"contactInfo": @{@"email":@"email"}, @"password":@"password"}, @"main": @{}}];
    RKRequestDescriptor *signupRequestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:signupRequestMapping objectClass:[SignupModel class] rootKeyPath:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Restkit doesn't support multipart encoding out of the box. You'd have to implement your own serializer. The following is a comment from RKObjectManager.h for the property requestSerializationMIMEType:

```
Implementations are provided by default for 'RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded' and 'RKMIMETypeJSON'.
```

If you really need to send your image as raw binary, then I don't see any option other than to implement your own serializer. However, what I do is convert the image to a base64 string and then use either of the two standard serializations.